# To what extent am I excluding content that I might find interesting/relevant when using Personalized Predictions?

Tags: support, profile-page

I like how the personalized predictions feature is working for me. I don't know how strongly that feature affects the results that I see, however.

Am I likely to be missing things that might be (or become) relevant to me when I have this feature enabled, or is the weight of the predictions sufficiently moderate that I will still see all kinds of things to some extent?

Comment: You do know you can access your prediction data: http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't tell me how strongly the data affects the results that I am seeing.

Comment: This question got some down-votes right away. I don't resent down-votes if my entry is annoying, disruptive, or whatever. I do appreciate comments about why down-voted though, so I know what to try to do differently in the future.

Comment: Nah, some users might not know about prediction and your question is somewhat vague.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [your predication data](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) and download it to see what Stack Overflow uses to tailor your results.

[image]

You can disable predictions for a while to see how you're doing with just favorite and ignored tags.
In your profile you edit your favourite tag (they will show up with a reddish background) and your ignored tags. Those can either be hidden (bye, bye PHP) or grayed out.

Comment: I guess that leads to a follow-up question of how strongly my favorite tags are affecting my results. :)

Comment: Favouriting will only change its appearance, with ignore you can choose to  hide (bye, bye PHP) or gray out

Comment: Ah. I did notice see the different appearance. I didn't know that was specifically because of favorite tags. I do seem to be seeing more of questions with a tag that I just added to favorites than I did before adding, though, so that does seem to be affecting my results — in a good way, but still.